color customization commands from hf-tikz are coming up as undefined
Ref: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/731535/319072

On page 6 of the hf-tikz manual, it talks about customizing the colors. I have tried to use the manual's syntax, but neither \hfsetfillcolor{black}, \hfsetbordercolor{black}, set fill color, nor set border color are defined when I call them. Is there a dependency I am missing?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hf-tikz}
\begin{document}
\hfsetfillcolor{red}
\hfsetbordercolor{green}
\[\tikzmarkin[set fill color=blue,set border color=yellow]{a}1+1=2\tikzmarkend{a}\]
\end{document}


This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024)  (format=lualatex 2024.3.29)  24 NOV 2024 04:34
 system commands enabled.
**MWE.tex
(./MWE.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-03-14>
Lua module: luaotfload 2024-02-14 3.28 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended collection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/home/tex/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2023-12-28.lua" from kpse-resolved path "/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2023-12-28.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.134
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 2
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/home/tex/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_truetype_file'.
Removing  `luaotfload.glyph_stream' from `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.glyphstream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 3
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' in `luaotfload.patch_font_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' in `input_level_string'. (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /home/tex/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz)
\c@part=\count186
\c@section=\count187
\c@subsection=\count188
\c@subsubsection=\count189
\c@paragraph=\count190
\c@subparagraph=\count191
\c@figure=\count192
\c@table=\count193
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen139
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hf-tikz/hf-tikz.sty
Package: hf-tikz 2014/07/25 v0.3a A simple way to highlight formulas and formula parts.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks17
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen140
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen141
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box51
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
Package: pgf 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks18
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 107.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def
File: luatex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2d Graphics/color driver for luatex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen142
\Gin@req@width=\dimen143
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks19
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks20
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks21
))
\pgf@x=\dimen144
\pgf@y=\dimen145
\pgf@xa=\dimen146
\pgf@ya=\dimen147
\pgf@xb=\dimen148
\pgf@yb=\dimen149
\pgf@xc=\dimen150
\pgf@yc=\dimen151
\pgf@xd=\dimen152
\pgf@yd=\dimen153
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2
\c@pgf@counta=\count194
\c@pgf@countb=\count195
\c@pgf@countc=\count196
\c@pgf@countd=\count197
\t@pgf@toka=\toks22
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks23
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks24
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count198
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-luatex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-luatex.def
File: pgfsys-luatex.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count199
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count266
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2023/11/15 v3.01 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 274.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1350.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1354.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen154
\pgfmath@count=\count267
\pgfmath@box=\box52
\pgfmath@toks=\toks25
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks26
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks27
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count268
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen155
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen156
\pgf@picminy=\dimen157
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen158
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen159
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen160
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen161
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen162
\pgf@xx=\dimen163
\pgf@xy=\dimen164
\pgf@yx=\dimen165
\pgf@yy=\dimen166
\pgf@zx=\dimen167
\pgf@zy=\dimen168
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen169
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen170
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen171
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen172
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfpic=\box53
\pgf@hbox=\box54
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box55
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count269
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen173
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen174
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen175
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen176
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen177
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@max=\dimen178
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count270
\pgf@shadingcount=\count271
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box56
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box57
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen179
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen180
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen181
\pgffor@skip=\dimen182
\pgffor@stack=\toks28
\pgffor@toks=\toks29
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count272
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen183
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen184
\tikz@lasty=\dimen185
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen186
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen187
\tikz@lastmovetox=\dimen188
\tikz@lastmovetoy=\dimen189
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen190
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen191
\tikz@figbox=\box58
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box59
\tikz@tempbox=\box60
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box61
\tikztreelevel=\count273
\tikznumberofchildren=\count274
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count275
\tikz@fig@count=\count276
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count277
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count278
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count279
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count280
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshadings.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryshadings.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryshadings.code.tex
File: pgflibraryshadings.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2024-03-14 L3 programming layer (loader) 
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2024-03-14 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count281
Inserting `l3color' in `luaotfload.parse_color'.
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box62
))
Package: xparse 2024-03-14 L3 Experimental document command parser
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count282
)) (./output.aux)
\openout1 = output.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 3.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2023/04/13 v2.5m Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count283
\scratchdimen=\dimen192
\scratchbox=\box63
\nofMPsegments=\count284
\nofMParguments=\count285
\everyMPshowfont=\toks30
\MPscratchCnt=\count286
\MPscratchDim=\dimen193
\MPnumerator=\count287
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count288
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks31
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 485.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
))
! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 \hfsetfillcolor
                 {red}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 \hfsetbordercolor
                   {green}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 6.

! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/set fill color', to which you passed 'blue', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.6 ... fill color=blue,set border color=yellow]{a}1
                                                  +1=2\tikzmarkend{a}\]
This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/set border color', to which you passed 'yellow', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.6 ... fill color=blue,set border color=yellow]{a}1
                                                  +1=2\tikzmarkend{a}\]
(That was another \errmessage.)

[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
Missing character: There is no ; (U+003B) in font nullfont!
] (./output.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-03-14>
 ***********
)

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 12573 strings out of 476435
 100000,1977958 words of node,token memory allocated
 417 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 6 attribute, 48 glue_spec, 6 attribute_list, 2 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:166,3:103,4:10,5:22,6:2,7:118,8:7,9:58
 34342 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 25 fonts using 1345055 bytes
 117i,7n,114p,425b,695s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on output.pdf (1 page, 11622 bytes).

PDF statistics: 22 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 14 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 16 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)


You need to specify the customcolors option when loading the package to make those macros available. The following compiles for me, though I think the colour palette needs some work.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\begin{document}
\hfsetfillcolor{red}
\hfsetbordercolor{green}
\[\tikzmarkin[set fill color=blue,set border color=yellow]{a}1+1=2\tikzmarkend{a}\]
\end{document}

The answer you linked doesn't need the option because it uses only the default colours.
